# Telerik RadGrid stopped populating data after I removed RadScriptManager

Tags: telerik-grid

I have a `Telerik RadGrid` and a "Search" button to search for a specific data.

My page used to have `RadScriptManager`. Now `RadScriptManager` is placed on Master page and I had to remove it from my page.

After I removed it, the grid on my page stopped being repopulated

Here is some part of the code:

```
   <%-- <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />--%>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ajaxControl">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="btnSearch"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

    <telerik:RadButton RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Text="Search" ID="btnSearch" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"></telerik:RadButton>

<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel2" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
      <telerik:RadGrid 
 
  ....Here come a Grid Code....

        </telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

I used the wrong control ids for `AjaxUpdatedControl` and `AjaxSetting` elements.

I had to change it to be as follows:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager" runat="server">
<AjaxSettings>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnSearch">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="GridID"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

So, basically:
`AjaxSetting` control's id should've been id of my button
`AjaxUpdatedControl` control's id should've been id of my grid

Hope that helps someone with the same problem

Comment: You still need to have a script manager on the page (and you do, since it works), that is required by all iscriptcontrol implementations (like telerik's). Also, remove the radajaxpanel around the grid, the radajaxmanager setting replaces it

Comment: Script manager was moved to master page